# Using numpy.savetxt not working for long doubles

Tags: numpy, gis, scientific-notation, rounding

I'm trying to export a GIS attribute table to csv using numpy.savetxt but my values are rounded and displayed in scientific notation whatever value I seem to set for the fmt.

Basically I have two fields of interest in the attribute table, say X and Y. X contains values of length 11 and Y contains values of length 16 - they both also contain NULLs. Both columns have the type set to double in GIS.

If I set `fmt = '%12.0f,%16.0f'` the resulting file has scientific notation. However, if I click on any value in X in the csv it doesn't appear to have been rounded, whereas the values in Y have been rounded so are useless to me.

Ideally, I'd like to export the values as integers but if I set `fmt = '%12d,%16d'` I get the following error...

```
Runtime error 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.2\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\npyio.py", line 1047, in savetxt
    fh.write(asbytes(format % tuple(row) + newline))
TypeError: %d format: a number is required, not numpy.float64
```

which I thought might be because I have nulls.

Can anyone help?

Comment: The error line shows what is trying to do - use ordinary python print formatting to convert a row of your array into a string.  `fmt%tuple(row)`.

Comment: `savetxt` saves a numpy array.  Show how you use it with this 'attribute table'.